# How to delete the test case of sublime test while using CPP Fast Olympic Coding?

Tags: c++, sublimetext

I am using CPP Fast Olympic coding for Competitive programming. And i am using  **"tests_file_suffix": "__tests"** this line to save my input. But I want to delete all the test cases after completion of my program. Is there any keyboard shortcut for doing this? Because it is too much time-consuming pressing edit and deletes the test case when there is too much test case for a program.

Comment: Unrelated. Why do people do "fast olympic coding" but not "fast olympic surgery"? Programming is not about speed, but about correctness, readability and beauty.

Comment: Actually, this tool is very much helpful for competitive programming as it provides different facilities.

Comment: I think the point of @Evg's comment is that programming is fundamentally not just about how quickly you can code and compile a working program, in the same way that surgery is not about how quickly a surgeon can removed a damaged kidney, for example. Yes, doing the work in a reasonable amount of time is one item that you should think about, but there are many others that are much more important, such as not introducing bugs (or not removing the wrong kidney in surgery).

Answer (score 1):

You can use ctrl+d to delete the test cases, or ctrl+a+d if you want to delete all the test cases at once.